# Add Visitor Country into PHPMail

Tags: email, phpmailer, php

I got a script that showing visitor country. I want to add it into PHPMail but don't know how to do it because that is create by a function.
Can anyone please suggest me any way to add it on PHPMail, So i also get visitor country when they submit contact form.

Get visitor country script=

```
  function visitor_country()
   {
  $client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
  $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
  $remote  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  $result  = "Unknown";
  if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
  {
 $ip = $client;
  }
 elseif(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
 {
 $ip = $forward;
 }
 else
 {
$ip = $remote;
 }

$ip_data = @json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=".$ip));

if($ip_data && $ip_data->geoplugin_countryName != null)
{
$result = $ip_data->geoplugin_countryName;
}

return $result;
}

echo visitor_country(); // Output Coutry name [Ex: United States]

?>
```

My PHPMail code-

```
<?php

//--Mail Server Setup----------------------------------
ini_set("SMTP", "mail.$_SERVER[SERVER_NAME]");
ini_set("smtp_port", 25);
ini_set("sendmail_from", "info@$_SERVER[SERVER_NAME]");
ini_set("memory_limit", "1024M");

//-----------------------------------------------------

if($_POST['submit']){
$email_msg="
Advertising Inquiries Request, Details Below:   

Name: $_POST[name]
Company: $_POST[company]
Email: $_POST[email]    
Phone: $_POST[phone]    
Geo Targeting: $_POST[geo_targeting]
Website: $_POST[website]
Message: $_POST[message]    

IP: ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']." 
";
$headers .= 'From: Arif Khan<arif@uposonghar.com>';    
if(mail("arifkpi@gmail.com", "Advertising Inquiries", $email_msg, $headers));   
header("location:index.html");
}

?>
```

Comment: Can't you just add the country information to the `$email_msg`?

Comment: No, i don't know to how to echo a function within $email_msg

Comment: Excuse me, but you definitely need to learn the *basics* of PHP first. If you can not even put two strings together you’re definitely missing the basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take off echo visitor_country(); in your ip script above. it should be its own script with no echos... then:

PHPMail Code:

```
<?php
include("NAME_OF_VISITOR_COUNTRY_SCRIPT.php");
//--Mail Server Setup----------------------------------
ini_set("SMTP", "mail.$_SERVER[SERVER_NAME]");
ini_set("smtp_port", 25);
ini_set("sendmail_from", "info@$_SERVER[SERVER_NAME]");
ini_set("memory_limit", "1024M");

//-----------------------------------------------------

if($_POST['submit']){
$email_msg="
Advertising Inquiries Request, Details Below:   

Name: $_POST[name]
Company: $_POST[company]
Email: $_POST[email]    
Phone: $_POST[phone]    
Country: ".visitor_country()."
Geo Targeting: $_POST[geo_targeting]
Website: $_POST[website]
Message: $_POST[message]    

IP: ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']." 
";
$headers .= 'From: Arif Khan<arif@uposonghar.com>';    
if(mail("arifkpi@gmail.com", "Advertising Inquiries", $email_msg, $headers));   
header("location:index.html");
}

?>
```